# How to change the background box based on input value in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here i'm trying to change the color based on value and rest of should be in white background, if input value is 1 then it should highlighted to red ,  if i changed the value to 4 then it should be highlighted in to red and rest of values 1 should be in white

I am still learning,Thanks in advance

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td id="data1">1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<input type="text" id="valuesData" />
<button onclick="myFunction()" value="click me"></button>
</body>


<script>
   function myFunction(){
    if(document.getElementById('valuesData').value >= '9'){
    document.getElementById('data1').style.background='red' 
      }
   else{
   alert("value should not be greater than 9");
   }
   }
    
</script>
```

Comment: You are making a typo in if statement; it should check for <= 9

Comment: Whats are you trying to do  ? please add your expected output results

Comment: Suppose input value is 2 then the box of 2 should be highlighted to red , again if I pass the value of other number then that number should be highlighted and no of 2 value should be in white

Comment: It is working fine you just have a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to see which td has a `value` of the entered text. It will change the background of entered value `td`.

Also before applying the `background red` to the entered value we can check all the tds and clear them with `white` background.

All the value entered in an input are string format so we need to use `parseInt` function to make sure they are converted to `integar`.

**Live Demo:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  //Get input value and convert to int using parseInt
  let value = parseInt(document.getElementById('valuesData').value)
  //Clear all the td with white background
  let allTds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (let i = 0; i < allTds.length; i++) {
    allTds.item(i).style.background = 'white'
  }
  //Apply red background to the entered td with matching data-id
  let getTd = document.querySelector('[data-id="' + value + '"]');
  if (value <= '9') {
    getTd.style.background = 'red'
  } else {
    alert("value should not be greater than 9");
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-id="1">1</td>
    <td data-id="2">2</td>
    <td data-id="3">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-id="4">4</td>
    <td data-id="5">5</td>
    <td data-id="6">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-id="7">7</td>
    <td data-id="8">8</td>
    <td data-id="9">9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="valuesData" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it. There were a few errors originally:

1. You were comparing the string value of the input to the string value `'9'` - the input should either be changed from `text` to `number`, or you should use `parseInt` as I have. Note, that entering a non-numeric value will cause an error unless it is checked for, so it's better to change the input field's type to `number` - also, you should compare to the numeric value `9`, rather than the string value `'9'`
2. Your conditional was actually the wrong way around - i.e. `>=` should be `<=` in this case

Updated:

```
   function myFunction() {

     var val = document.getElementById('valuesData').value;
       document.querySelectorAll("table td").forEach(function(td) {
       td.style.background = "";
     })

     if (document.getElementById('valuesData').value != "" && parseInt(document.getElementById('valuesData').value) <= 9) {
       val = parseInt(val);
       document.querySelectorAll("table td")[val - 1].style.background = 'red';
     } else {
       alert("value should be between 1 and 9");
     }
   }
```

Comment: But when I'm passing the input value 5 , only  1 box is highlighting with red ..but the  box 5 hould have  to be highlighted right

Comment: Ok, I didn't realise that's what you wanted to do. I have upload the code. You can also remove the `.forEach` loop if you don't want the board to be cleared each time. Realistically though, a better approach to this would be to use a custom attribute as the others have done - for 9 squares, it's not to bad, but if you wanted to make a bigger board - let's say a 20x20 or something, it'd be best to create the `td` elements on the the fly using javascript/jquery. The css `display: grid` layout is also probably easier/more flexible than creating lots of `<tr>` tags too...

Comment: Likewise, if you want to remove the colour from the previously selected one, it'd be more efficient to store that in a `lastSelected` variable or something, then just remove the background, rather than looping through all 9 (in this case, trivial, since it'd take like 0.00001ms probably...but supposing you had a much bigger board/were doing computationally-intensive processing)...

Answer (score 0):

```
 <body>
    <input type="text" id="valuesData" />
 <button onclick="myFunction()" value="click me"></button>
 </body>
<script>
function myFunction(){
 if(document.getElementById('valuesData').value >= 9){
 document.getElementById('data1').style.background='red' 
   }
else{
alert("value should not be greater than 9");
}
}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(){
const value= parseInt(document.getElementById('valuesData').value);
 if( value<= 9){
 const set=document.getElementsByClassName('data1')
 for (item of set){
     if(item.innerHTML==value){item.style.background='red'
     }else item.style.background='white';
 }
   }
else{
alert("value should not be greater than 9");
}
}
```

```html
     <table>
<tr>
<td class="data1">1</td>
<td class="data1">2</td>
<td class="data1">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="data1">4</td>
<td class="data1">5</td>
<td class="data1">6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="data1">7</td>
<td class="data1">8</td>
<td class="data1">9</td>
</tr>

</table>
 <input type="text" id="valuesData" />
 <button onclick="myFunction()" value="click me"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all `tds` and check if the user input matches with your `td` and based on you can change the color i.e. `red` and for rest of the `tds` make it white

```js
function myFunction(){
    var input = parseInt(document.getElementById('valuesData').value);
    if(!isNaN(input) && input>=1 && input<=9)
            document.getElementsByTagName('td')[input-1].style.background='red';
    else
        alert('invalid input')
      
    let allTds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
        for(let i=0;i<allTds.length;i++){
        if(i!==input-1){
        allTds.item(i).style.background='white'
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <input type="text" id="valuesData" />
  <button onclick="myFunction()" value="click me">Click</button>
</body>
```